# Full dynamic router in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

By default you have the following URL-syntax in ZF: /module/controller/action. What i want, is to build an menu-system where i can use any URL I want.

Lets say I make an menu-item called 'news'. When i call http://www.site.com/news i want to have the folowing loaded:

- module: news
- controller: frontpage
- action: display

These config-values must be configured in the database-record for the menu-item.

How can I do this in zend? I spend a lot of time searching for it, but I still can't figure out how to. Does anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a plugin and in routeStartup define something that intercept your request and route `/module/controller/action` to `/action`, but for this all your action names must be unique :

```
  class My_CustomRouterPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
    {
        public function routeStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
        {

            $fc = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
            $action =$fc->getRequest()->getActionName();

            $router = $fc->getRouter();

            $model= new myModel();      
            $myPage = $model->getPageByAction($action);

            $route =  new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/action', array(
                            'module' => $myPage->getModule();
                            'controller' => $myPage->getController();
                            'action' => $action;

                        ));

             $router->addRoute($action, $route);
             return $router;
            }
    }
```

In myModel define a method can get you  an object(or an array) that contains module, controller names (from you DB ).

and register this plugin in your bootstrap:

```
$front->registerPlugin(new My_CustomRouterPlugin());
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a front controller plugin to scan your database for all the entries, create routing rules based on those entries and add them to the router [(see this)](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html).

Of course caching strategy is recommended so that you don't do a lot of processing on every request.

Comment: Can't I just load only the used item?

Comment: Yes, you can. But if you want to generate nice links to other pages (using the `url` view helper), you will need all (well, potentially all) the routes defined anyway.